# Centre uibutton text on a certain word

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Is it possible to centre the text of a uibutton based on a certain word?
I.e. "Manchester United vs Chelsea" where the text is centred on the word "vs"

Comment: Better take a view and align 3 labels with `vs` in the middle and equal width team names, add tap gesture to button

Comment: @Daniel Jeffery Welcome to S.O. It would be very helpful if you cited research have already done on this subject or if you included what you have already tried.

Comment: Thanks Mr.UB, this is the approach I have been working on, but thought there might have been a way to action without the need for labels etc...